# Type NodeListOf<HTMLLabelElement> is not assignable to type NgIterable<HTMLLabelElement> | QueryList<HTMLLabelElement>

Tags: angular, typescript

For some reason this HTML element throws this error, which makes no real sense to me as it's just an *ngFor loop ...

```
  <a class = "article-label" *ngFor="let label of articleData.labels" (click)="addLabelLocal(label.text)">{{label.text}}</a>
```

I don't even know where to start with this. What should I do to address this?

This is part of a "Search items by choosing labels" app, like a lot of eCommerce sites. In this case, the items are articles.

**articleData** is just an object with Subject, Author, and Labels info. It currently has type: ArticleResponseObject.

```
export class ArticlesResponseObject{
   response:any;
}
```

(response.{complex object})

**addLabelLocal** is a method that allows users to add a label (text query) to a search. Calls a Service that adds a search query label to the search.

Comment: Can you add more information about your controller data, like articleData or addLabelLocal()

Comment: Please show how 'articleData.labels' is created and which type it has.